# How to pronounce consonants especially /t/ on following scenarios of American English?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation

Scenarios
————————-

1. Do we release the sound of all consonants that appear at the end of the word ending a sentence ?

Eg: I am at work. There was a Big Bang. I have a new hope. He has a big heart.

2. In the case of /t/, I have learnt that you pronounce it as STOP at the end of the word if its preceded by vowel and not followed by another vowel. But you release it if the ending /t/ is a part of consonant cluster. So, how do you pronounce sentences in following examples ?

Eg: There was a bright light. It was his night shift.

3. It is also said that in American English, /t/ after /n/ is silent. So, how do you pronounce the last /t/ after /n/ in a word ending the sentence as shown in the following examples ?

Eg: The surrounding was silent. It is a beautiful environment. It was his the best moment.

Comment: For (3), not all Americans pronounce a /t/ after /n/, but I believe the majority do. And that's the way most people in other English-speaking countries pronounce it, so there's no reason for you to learn a pronunciation used by a minority of Americans which might confuse people Australians or Brits. Pronounce /t/ after /n/ unless for some reason you find it hard to do so.

Comment: Ahmm can you help me with other scenarios too ? @Peter Shor

Comment: In the third case, /t/ is *not silent*. It's what's called the *vanishing t*. After 'n' in an unstressed syllable, the 't' in rapid speech vanishes. So *internet* becomes *innernet*. (I think you should divide your question into three questions).

Comment: @Decapitated Soul: I assume you mean after an 'n' and **before** an unstressed syllable; *internet* is stressed on the first syllable.

Comment: In the third case, /t/ is not silent. It's what's called the vanishing t. After 'n' **and before** an unstressed syllable, the 't' in rapid speech vanishes. So internet becomes innernet (corrected; see above).